# Android=Count clicks in Kotlin: How can I count number clicks Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, count, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to show interstitial ads on clicking the button for specific number of times. How can I achieve it in kotlin?
Help me please
my MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
mMyButton.setOnClickListener {
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
    mInterstitialAd.show()
} else {
    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
}
 }
  }
```

Comment: Post what you tried? what kind of problem you faced on that?

Comment: I've updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example code that can get you desired behaviour

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  var clickCount = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener { 
           clickCount++
           if (clickCount >= 5 && interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
           clickCount = 0 // reset count
           interstitialAd.show()
        }
   }
}
```